# Open bootstrap 3 accordion panel from another page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

here is my accordion code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body" id="myPanelContent">
        Accordion Panel 1 Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Accordion Panel 2 Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want a link from another page to open the No 1 panel (#myPanelContent) and show the content.
Link example:

```
<a href="mynewpage.html#myPanelContent">Go to Panel 1 content</a>
```

The true is that i used some solutions from stackoverflow but not worked. A detailed explain how to use the code will be much appreciated as I am novice in javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you could check if a hash is present (`window.location.hash`), and then trigger the accordion panel, something like `$('.collapse').removeClass('in');$(window.location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');`

Comment: well as said I am novice or better "just started" in java so can you please be more specific. Panels are closed as there are no "in" in collapse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add an answer in reply to my comment.

you need to check if there is a hash present in the URL, if so then show the accordion panel, you can accomplish this likes so:

```
$(function(){

    // check if there is a hash in the url
    if ( window.location.hash != '' )
    {
        // remove any accordion panels that are showing (they have a class of 'in')
        $('.collapse').removeClass('in');

        // show the panel based on the hash now:
        $(window.location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');
    }

});
```

This code uses jQuery of course, but i'd imagine you are using that already if you are using bootstrap's accordion?

Comment: my link from another page must be: href="mynewpage.html#myPanelContent or
href="mynewpage.html#collapseOne

Comment: Thats fine, the javascript here needs to go on the same page as your accordion. it will detect the #myPanelContent in the URL.

Comment: Thank you my friend it worked! The trick for me was to change $ to jQuery.

Comment: Thanks again, just to add that link must be href="mynewpage.html#collapseOne, at least that way worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="identity.html#students"></a> 
give the link like above mentioned
and add the below script in the page where you want to show the active div

<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = window.location.toString();
     if (url.match('#')) {
      $('.nav-tabs a[href="#'+url.split('#')[1]+'"]').tab('show');
    }

</script>
```