# Opening Bootstrap 4 accordions using URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, accordion

If I was to use this accordion example (pasted below) - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/
and place it in a file named *test-bootstrap.html* how would I format a URL to open the accordion?
I am happy to modify the HTML file if I can get the results I need.

I appreciate that there are answers to this question on Stack Overflow but these refer to older versions of Bootstrap or involves clicking on links.

The CMS I am using can construct a URL similar to these  -

file:///C:/Users/dvb/Desktop/test-bootstrap.html#collapseOne or

file:///C:/Users/dvb/Desktop/test-bootstrap.html#1

```
 <html>
    <head>
      [appropriate libraries added]
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="accordion">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Collapsible Group Item #1
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        Collapsible Group Item #2
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                        Collapsible Group Item #3
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a really basic example.

If you append `?collapseExample` to your URL where `collapseExample` is the ID of the collapse div you want to show, and then add the Javascript AFTER the HTML code, it will add the `show` class to the div onload.

You can tidy up the Javascript if you want to break the appended strings down into variables and values.

```js
if (window.location.search == '?collapseExample') {
  $('#collapseExample').addClass('show');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel.  I have amended your response to get it to work in my example.  All working now :)

Comment: Ahhh!  The tick symbol.  I was wondering how to accept.  I am new to asking questions on Stack Overflow. Thanks a million Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel's answer above and Stuart's response here [Open bootstrap 3 accordion panel from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843213/open-bootstrap-3-accordion-panel-from-another-page) I have been able to get things running more or less the way I wanted.

Unfortunately I have had to move the identifier (shown as a simple number here) from the ID to the class.  I amended the code to that below.

My simple URL file:///C:/Users/dvb/Desktop/test-bootstrap.html#1 (or #2, #3 etc)

```
<head>
[appropriate libraries added]
</head>
<body>
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse 1" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse 2" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                Collapsible Group Item #3
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div  class="collapse 3" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


<script>
//checks if hash value exists
if ( window.location.hash != '' ) {
//removes the initial hash
openval = window.location.hash.slice(1);
//opens the relavant accordion
$('.' + openval).addClass('show');

}
</script>
```